# Table update to set correct date-time for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server (2019) table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[log_Current](
   [line_number] [int] NULL,
   [Time] [time](7) NULL,
   [server_time_initial] [datetime] NULL,
   [Correct_Date_Time] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Data:

| line_number | Time | server_time_initial | Correct_Date_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 69 | 07:05:08.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 | NULL |
| 72 | 07:05:25.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 73 | 07:05:30.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 215 | 16:34:36.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 216 | 16:56:01.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 283 | 21:06:02.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 284 | 21:08:52.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 511 | 23:57:06.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 512 | 23:57:07.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 513 | 00:00:05.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 514 | 00:01:57.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 633 | 02:49:06.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 634 | 02:49:08.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 1074 | 05:13:58.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 1075 | 05:13:59.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 1888 | 23:53:52.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 1889 | 23:54:08.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 1890 | 00:00:16.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |
| 1891 | 00:00:16.0000000 | 2021-05-15 07:05:05.000 |  |

etc.....

Fields:

- [server_time_initial] is the same for all rows and represents the time when log has been extracted. Equal to 2021-05-15 07:05:05
- [line_number] is the log entry order
- [Time] is the time of the log entry but unfortunately does not have the date as well.
- Correct_Date_Time - Must be filled with correct date + time for each line. As you can see, time entries start sometime in the morning (not necessarily at O AM) and then go past midnight, etc... and this pattern continues for several days.
  The first batch, representing time from 07:05:08 to 23:57:07, up to [line_number] 512 are entered on 2021-05-15. From [line_number] 513 is the next day, i.e. 2021-05-16, up to [line_number] 1889. Then, from [line_number] 1890, the entry date is 2021-05-17, etc....

Desired result should have [Correct_Date_Time] column updated:

```
  **line_number  Time       server_time_initial**    Correct_Date_Time
  69    07:05:08.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000      2021-05-15 07:05:08
  72    07:05:25.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000      2021-05-15 07:05:25 
  73    07:05:30.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000      2021-05-15 07:05:30   
 215    16:34:36.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000      2021-05-15 16:34:36 
 216    16:56:01.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000           etc...
 283    21:06:02.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000
 284    21:08:52.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000
 511    23:57:06.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000
 512    23:57:07.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000      2021-05-15 23:57:07
 513    00:00:05.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000      2021-05-16 00:00:05
 514    00:01:57.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000            etc...
 633    02:49:06.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000
 634    02:49:08.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000
 1074   05:13:58.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000
 1075   05:13:59.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000
 1888   23:53:52.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000
 1889   23:54:08.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000    2021-05-16 23:54:08 
 1890   00:00:16.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000    2021-05-17 00:00:16 
 1891   00:00:31.0000000    2021-05-15 07:05:05.000    2021-05-17 00:00:31
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Please update your question with your best attempt at resolving this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag([Time])` to compare the `[Time]` to find the cross over to next day

```
[Time] < lag([Time]) over (order by line_number)
```

for the line after cross over, d = 1 else 0

```
d = case when [Time] < lag([Time]) over (order by line_number)
         then 1
         else 0 
         end
```

and with that you can calculate cumulative number of days of offset from the beginning (total days offset)

```
sum(d) over (order by line_number)
```

To set the time to `00:00:00`

```
dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, server_time_initial), 0)
```

and

```
Final corrected time = server_time_initial (with Time 00:00:00)
                     + total days offset
                     + [Time]
```

---

Put it all together,

```
with cte
as 
(
    select  *,
            d = case when [Time] < lag([Time]) over (order by line_number)
                     then 1
                     else 0 
                     end
    from    [log_Current]
)
select  *,
        dateadd(day,
                sum(d) over (order by line_number),
                dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, server_time_initial), 0) )
        + convert(varchar(10), [Time], 108) as Correct_Date_Time
from    cte
order by line_number
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=daab9bb7bf11f6030edd600bc7b5385c)

Comment: Thank you Squirrel for your help, very nice solution!